# Not sure why split normals remain in the same position after smooth shading applied

Tags: normals

In this image you can see that I have two connected planes and I am showing the vertex normal and the split normals. I do not have smooth shading or auto smooth on.

[image]

This is how the last image displays with a hard edge in object mode

[image]

I now enable auto smooth and the edge is smoothed. Note that the vertex and split normals remain the same as they were when auto smooth was not turned on. I would have expected that the split normals change to be the same as the vertex normal.

[image]

I then turn on auto smooth at 30 degrees. The smoothing result remains the same but the split normals move to the vertex normal position.

[image]

Is there are reason why when I put smoothing on the split normals remained in the same position?

thank you

Comment: I think the current behavior is correct because smooth shading is an interpolation over the barycentric coordinates per face. Therefore the split normals (vertex-per-face normals) aren't affected by smooth shading. Auto-smooth on the other hand works on the curvature of adjacent faces.

Comment: thanks rjg. Just looked up barycentric and non the wiser. I believe that smooth shading is calculated on adjacent faces and is averaged over those faces. In this case if the top face were smaller on the X (image in orig question) the vertex normal would remain in the same rotation but the shading would change as the face size has changed? thanks again

Comment: Smooth shading uses the vertex normals to interpolate the normals for every point of the face in between. Since it uses the vertex normals to calculate, they can't be affected/changed by the different shading model. See https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/introduction-to-shading/shading-normals the section "Flat Shading vs. Smooth Shading and Vertex Normals"

Comment: Thank you. Just been reading the article and will go and read around it. I guess not seeing the vector normal auto move when I made a change such as flat to smooth shade confused me. I need to gen up on this stuff - thanks again rjg